# How to display JSON content using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

`JSON.stringify()` displays content in `JSON` format.I would like the quote in `quote` class and character in `character` class.So that on click of button i'll get message and quote displayed.

```
//HTML

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <h2>GOT Quotes</h2>
  </div>
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12 well quote">
      The message will go here
      <br>
      <div class = "col-xs-12 well character">
        Said By
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
      <button id = "getMessage" class = "btn btn-primary">
        Get Message
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

//JS

<script>$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#getMessage').click(function () {
        $.getJSON('https://got-quotes.herokuapp.com/quotes', function (json) {
            $('.quote').html(JSON.stringify(json));
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Show some JSON too

Comment: The `json` parameter is misnamed because it contains an object, not JSON. There is no reason to use `JSON.stringify()` to turn it back into JSON, just access the properties you need directly. For help with this you'll need to show a sample of the actual JSON structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? Note that I moved the `quote` class down to a `span` within the `div` so you don't overwrite the nested `character` `div`. I also used `.text()` instead of `.html()`. This is the right thing to do if you're dealing with text.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#getMessage').click(function () {
        $.getJSON('https://got-quotes.herokuapp.com/quotes', function (data) {
            $('.quote').text(data.quote);
            $('.character').text(data.character);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <h2>GOT Quotes</h2>
  </div>
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12 well">
      <span class="quote">The message will go here</span>
      <br>
      <div class = "col-xs-12 well character">
        Said By
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class = "row text-center">
    <div class = "col-xs-12">
      <button id = "getMessage" class = "btn btn-primary">
        Get Message
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```